# Magento - how to create multiple about-us page for different sotres

Tags: magento

HI can i get some help  i am new for magento..

I have 8 store views and for each store view i have one About-us page ..

how to create and manage them from admin section , FYI each about -us page has different 
data for each store.

I am using permission extension, so that each store owner is restricted to his own store.

I am able to create stores but the data is being accessed for all stores ( I mean if i update to

one store then it is reflected to other stores

Answer (score 0):

In Magento backend CMS -> pages you can create multiple pages and give each of them a url-key like about-store1, about-store2 and select the storeview for that page.

Now you can use:

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>about-store1"</a>
```

Etc.

Comment: Thank you .. do i need to add this code for … <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>about-magento-demo-store"</a> to access from all stores. I m implementing theme in my project

Comment: That's possible. Is my answer helpful?